# XAML: How to bind TabControl nested element to Attached Property of TabItem

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, tabcontrol, attached-properties

I have been searching for a "pure" XAML solution for this problem but just cannot find it.
My goal would be to *only* create an Attached Property in code behind but the rest should be XAML only without creating a Custom Control or User Control. But I'm not sure whether this is possible at all and if, how to make the connection between a nested element inside the `TabControl` template and an Attached Property set in a `TabItem`

I'd have a boilerplate Attached Property of `string` with `[AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TabItem))]` and/or `[AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TabControl))]` inside my `MainWindow` class and the following XAML

```
<Window x:Class="AP_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AP_Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="800">

  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Grid Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <TabPanel Name="headerPanel" 
                                  Background="Transparent" 
                                  Grid.Column="0" 
                                  IsItemsHost="true" 
                                  Margin="2,2,2,0" 
                                  Grid.Row="0" 
                                  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" 
                                  Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
              <Border Name="contentPanel" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                Grid.Column="0" 
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" 
                                Grid.Row="1" 
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" 
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                <DockPanel Background="White">
                  <Grid Name="TabControlHeader" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="65">
                    <Label x:Name="SelectedItemTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" Content="How to bind to AP ItemTitle?"/>
                  </Grid>

                  <Grid Name="Detail" Margin="8,0,8,8">
                    <Border BorderThickness="3,3,0,0" BorderBrush="DarkGray"  CornerRadius="3"/>
                    <Border BorderThickness="2,2,1,1" BorderBrush="LightGray" CornerRadius="3"/>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="3" Margin="3,3,-1,-1" Padding="5">
                      <Viewbox>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" 
                                                              ContentSource="SelectedContent" 
                                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                      </Viewbox>
                    </Border>
                  </Grid>
                </DockPanel>
              </Border>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  
  <TabControl x:Name="TabCtl">
    <TabItem Header="Tab1" local:MainWindow.ItemTitle="Tab1 Title" />
    <TabItem Header="Tab2" local:MainWindow.ItemTitle="Tab2 Title" />
    <TabItem Header="Tab3" local:MainWindow.ItemTitle="Tab3 Title" />
  </TabControl>
</Window>
```

I'd like the respective title entries to be displayed in the `TabControl`'s `SelectedItemTitle` label.

Any hints appreciated, even a definitive "That's not possible" would be good to know, so I can stop trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property (sub-)path for an attached property needs to be enclosed in parentheses:

```
Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.(local:MainWindow.ItemTitle),
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}}"
```

See [PropertyPath for Objects in Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#propertypath-for-objects-in-data-binding) for details.

---

An attached property is not even required. You could as well use the TabItem's `Tag` property like

```
<TabItem Header="Tab1" Tag="Tab1 Title"/>
```

with

```
Content="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Tag,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I only knew that was so simple, I would have asked here last week already. I feel so dumb now for searching up and down the net in the completely wrong direction.

Comment: Clemens, I just ran into another snag now. Originally I had the Attached Property defined inside the `MainWindow` class to keep it concise for a test project, but now I wanted to put the property in a dedicated public `CustomProperties` class. However, while in the former version I could use `UIElement` or `MainWindow` as the owning type in that dedicated class I only can use `Object`otherwise I get an exception "InvalidOperationException: Property path is not valid. 'cp' does not have a public property named 'ItemTitle'." 
Is there a way to be more precise with the owning type in such case?

Comment: Probably ask a new question, but a class that declares an attached property does not need a specific base class. All declarations are static: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#custom-attached-properties-

Comment: I may not have been clear - but will probably follow your suggestion to ask this in a separate question. What I meant was the third parameter in `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemTitle", typeof(string), typeof(UIElement), new PropertyMetadata("not set"));` not the base class for my `CustomProperties` class.

Comment: The third parameter is always the owner class, i.e. the class that declares the property: `typeof(CustomProperties)`

Comment: I see! Although that seems a bit redundant then 

Comment: Not at all. How else should the static property registration work? The RegisterAttached method does not know from where it is called.

Comment: In case you want to set that property on TabItems only, you may better create a derived TabItem class with a `Title` property.